# itertools.product in batches

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am using `itertools.product()` to get the Cartesian product of all the sub-lists of a list.

```
arr = [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
result = itertools.product(*arr)
```

However, `arr` can be a very large object `(2 <= len(arr) <= 500)`, so `result` can be even larger.

So, is there any way, I can do this operation in batches? or in any other way in which the objects occupy less memory ?

Comment: It returns an iterator, so it actually won't eat up all your memory. I.e. if you do `for result in product(*arr)` you will get one thing at a time. They'll only get stored in memory if you convert it to a list or tuple or something. But you'll notice your program will execute immediately with no wait as it stands, regardless of how big `arr` is. It only starts to generate the product as you iterate over it.

Comment: As written `result` will always be a constant sized iterator. If you materialize the entire iterator into a `list`, object, let's say, then the sizes will vary with the inputs. So, the answer to your question is: it's already processed in batches, **that's the whole point of itertools**

Comment: btw, suppose `len(arr) == 250`, and each internal `list` is only length 2, then the cartesian product would be of the size `2**250`, an *enormous number*, so it doesn't matter if it is memory efficient, [even if each iteration required 1 nanosecond](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2**250+nanoseconds), it would still require  ≈ 4.2×10^48 × **age of the universe** to complete

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.product` is already efficient because it returns an iterator: Its `O(n)` in memory complexity where `n` is the size of the list.

You could also use the function `powerset` defined in the [itertools recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) on python docs instead of `itertools.product`:

```py
def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

`powerset([1,2,3])` --> `() (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)`

---

However, an algorithm that iterates over all items on a [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) is `O(2^n)` in time complexity because the cardinality of a powerset is `2^n`.

The conclussion is that you will not be able to iterate over all items in a powerset of a list with size `n` if `n` is big